# Does my project use .NET Core or .NET Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm still trying to figure out the different versions of the .NET libraries.

Given an existing project, how do I know if it's using .NET Core or .NET Standard?

[image: Project Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is using standard .Net Framework.
In case if your project was using .NET Core that dropdown would look like below:
[image]

And like below if it was .NET Standard
[image]

Comment: @Matthew yes,exactly,  I have not said that it is :)

Answer (score 2):

.Net Core  and .Net Framework can use .Net Standard Libraries which is Shared Library for both.

The versions which is seen under drop down box is .Net Framework versions.

You cannot directly convert .Net Framework project using properties window. But, you can unload project and change `TargetFramework` to  `netcoreappx.x` by editing `.csproj` file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net Core that screen you've attached would look like this:

[image]

You will need to download the .Net Core framework, available here: [Download .Net Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral)

Then when you create a new app you select it to be a .Net Core application like so:

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the Application tab of unmodified project properties, whatever is selected in that drop down is the .NET framework your project is targeting...

Comment: Sure. But as you can see it says neither Standard or Core.

Comment: It says .NET Framework indicating it is targeting full .NET Framework, not standard or Core...

Answer (score -2):

This is a "standard" project.  The target framework is Framework not Core.

...Smells like homework